# Stop Windows 2003 queued error messages

Tags: windows-server-2003

Each time I reboot a Windows 2003 server, after Windows has restared I get message dialogs for all the application crashes that happened since the last reboot.

So after each reboot I have to click "Don't send" countless times, for crashes that happened weeks before.

How can the display of these error messages be stopped?

I'm connecting to the server through RDP, if that's relevant.

Here is a error message screenshot:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/190212/2009-12-17_104932.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you just have to disable the error reporting feature in the system properties.